# How to get the UID out of a processes status file with C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to get the user ID of who a process belongs to within a processes status file in /proc//status. I need to cast this data to an integer to be able to get who the user actually is but have no idea how to. This is the first few lines of the file

```
    Name:   kworker/0:0
    State:  S (sleeping)
    Tgid:   4
    Pid:    4
    PPid:   2
    TracerPid:  0
    Uid:    0   0   0   0
```

How would I go about getting just the UID? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: read file, get uid line, remove numbers, convert to integer, feed into getpwuid, read pw_name from passwd struct

Comment: I know what I'm supposed to do, it's the whole implementation of it that I don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

you can use `awk` to parse `/etc/passwd`:

```
 $ awk -F: '$3==XXXXX { print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Replace `XXXXX` with the UID.